# How to change relative paths to absolute paths in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I need to change relative paths to absolute paths in my WordPress page. My image links are broken in sub pages.

For example I need to change

```
../url/image.png
```

to

```
www.site.com/uploads/image.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your theme files, replace

```
<img src="../url/images.png">
```

with

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/url/images.png">
```

You can also do a search and replace. Search for `../` and replace with `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>`